# Cordova plugin with Cast Chrome Sender Framework API

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm trying to create an hybrid app using Ionic 5 that will cast some media. From docs

> The Chrome Sender API consists of two parts: the Framework API (cast.framework) and the Base API (chrome.cast)

I'm trying to find cordova plugin that provides me this functionality. Couple I've tried (like https://github.com/jellyfin/cordova-plugin-chromecast) have only the Base API (chrome.cast), but not the framework.

Is there any cordova plugin that provides both APIs or any other way of enabling framework?

I have also tried to use google lib for it: `https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1` but it requires `navigator.Presentation` to be accessible and it doesn't exist on WebView (also couldn't find any cordova plugin that provides `navigator.Presentation`).

Comment: I think cordova itself is using presention to work inside webview and to work with native hardware api's.  And it is navigator.presentation in lowercase , i will post in second comment an example.

Comment: navigator.presentation.receiver.connectionList.then(function (list) { list.connections.map(function (connection) { addConnection(connection); }); list.onconnectionavailable = function (evt) { addConnection(evt.connection); }; });

Comment: @Baumi Did you find any solution

Comment: @PrafulKadam Finally I made it working using `cordova-plugin-chromecast` posted in original question and using functionalities only from `chrome.cast`. End the end of the day this was sufficient for me.

Comment: @Baumi I get chrome is undefined error, do you know what's the issue

Comment: Are you adding https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js in your index file?

Comment: Also make sure to add attribute `data-cast-api-enabled="true"` to your head element in index file.